# how to pass object's function name as a parameter

Tags: python

What I am trying to do is something like this:

```
def custom_logger(user_logger, log_level, *args, **kwargs):    
    # do some stuff..
    user_logger.log_level(*args, **kwargs)
```

or like this:

```
def create_logger(module_name, log_level=DEBUG):
    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging.log_level)
```

How can I achieve something like this? Because it will clean up a lot of things.

Comment: You are mostly correct, but `kwargs` should have 2 asterisks: `**kwargs`.

Comment: Is your question how to _pass_ the function name in the caller, or how to _use_ the function name in the callee?

Comment: @jknotek, are you telling me that this code will work?

Comment: @JohnGordon, it is actually USE. sorry my bad.

Comment: @EzizDurdyyev Well, conceptually, yes, it will work. But I don't know anything about how your logger is implemented. So you'll have to try it yourself and debug as needed.

Comment: @jknotek, may be I am doing it wrong, but it is not working for now

Comment: As written, I don't believe this code will work, because it will call literally `user_logger.log_level()` instead of using whatever function name was passed as the `log_level` argument.

Comment: Actually, my mistake. @JohnGordon is right. I didn't realize that's what you were trying to do. You can use `getattr` as the answer suggests.

Comment: by the way, for `create_logger()` it is enough just to do: `logger.setLevel(log_level)` if `log_level` is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getattr` function to obtain an attribute by name:

```
def custom_logger(user_logger, log_level, *args, **kwargs):    
    log = getattr(user_logger, log_level) # or log_level.lower() if log_level is in upper case
    # do some stuff..
    log(*args, **kwargs)

def create_logger(module_name, log_level=DEBUG):
    logger = logging.getLogger(module_name)
    logger.setLevel(getattr(logging, log_level))
```

Comment: how can I apply this to create_logger?

Comment: @blhsubg, did you try it before you answered, or you sure this will work with loggers? again, may be i am doing it wrong but.. it won't work with me. sorry